# Pandas: Conditionally append substrings "y"+"z" to column B if column A contains "x"

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm trying to figure out how to conditionally add substrings per row to column `B` based on `regex` for column `A` in `pandas`.

Say I have this DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["BULL APPLE X2","BEAR APPLE X3","BULL GOOG 2X", 
                   "BEAR GOOG 3X", "BULL TSLA", "BEAR TSLA"], columns=["A"])
```

Desired output:

```
A                    B
"BULL APPLE X2"      "+200"
"BEAR APPLE X3"      "-300"
"BULL GOOG 2x"       "+200"
"BEAR GOOG 3x"       "-300"
"BULL TSLA"          "+100"
"BEAR TSLA"          "-100"
```

So, if `A` contains `"X2"`, take `"2"` with `regex` and add `"+"` before and `"00"` after, and write to `B`.

If it does not contain `Xn` or `nX`, then insert `"1"`.

Currently, I do this to get the numbers:

```
df["B"] = df["A"].str.extract(r"\sX(\d+)\s)", flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

(this is for `Xn` only, not `nX`).

From that, I would have to add `"+"` or `"-"` and `"00"` to `B` based on whether
`A` contains `BULL` or `BEAR`.

Comment: are there always X and some digit?

Comment: what should happen for \dX?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It can also be `\s(\d+)[Xx]` for multiplier 10x. It should still write so it becomes +1000 if BULL.

Comment: so it can be `BULL APPLE X2x`?

Comment: Just X2, x2, 2X or 2x :)

Comment: Ah ok but always has an xn/nx if you have a BULL or BEAR?

Comment: No it doesn't have to have xn/nx. But if it does have xn/nx and BULL then it is "+". If it has BEAR and xn/nx it is "-"

Comment: lol my brain is starting to ache, maybe add a few possibilities to your dataframe so we know what can and cannot be in there

Comment: Added more examples for different regex :) As well as if `n` is not present.

Comment: are `"-100"` and `"+100"` defaults?

Comment: Yes, or rather +100 is default, e.g. there is no X and no BEAR.

Comment: On another note will the digit always be there, can we actually ignore x? As in there will be no other digits after a space?

Comment: No there may be no digit (as in `BULL TSLA` so it's probably safer to use X as an selector for regex so that it doesn't confuse it with something else. Although it would be practical to ignore X. Maybe there's a way for regex to search for X in beginning alternatively in the end of expression? There won't be any more digits after `\s` however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you always had X followed by some number:

```
 r = re.compile(r"X(\d)$")

df["B"] = df["A"].map(lambda x: "+"+r.search(x).group(1)+"00"
                     if "BULL" in x else "-"+r.search(x).group(1)+"00"if "BEAR" in x else "")

print(df)

            A     B
0  BULL APPLE X2  +200
1  BEAR APPLE X3  -300
2  BULL APPLE X4  +400
```

I have a regex solution but it is ugly, depending on your data then splitting may do the job:

```
def f1(x):
    spl = x.rsplit(None, 1)[1].strip("Xx")
    if spl.isdigit():
        return "+" + spl + "00"
    return "+100"

def f2(x):
    spl = x.rsplit(None, 1)[1].strip("Xx")
    if spl.isdigit():
        return "-" + spl + "00"
    return "-100"


df = pd.DataFrame(["BULL APPLE X2", "BEAR APPLE X3", "BULL GOOG 2X", "BEAR GOOG 3X", "BULL TSLA", "BEAR TSLA","FOO BAR"],
              columns=["A"])


df["B"] = df["A"].map(lambda x: f1(x)
                  if "BULL" in x else f2(x) if "BEAR" in x else "+100")

print(df)
```

Output:

```
               A     B
0  BULL APPLE X2  +200
1  BEAR APPLE X3  -300
2   BULL GOOG 2X  +200
3   BEAR GOOG 3X  -300
4      BULL TSLA  +100
5      BEAR TSLA  -100
6        FOO BAR  +100
```

Unless you have other words made up of lower and upper case x's or just digits at the end of the string then splitting once from the end of the string and checking if we have a digit after stripping should work

Comment: Thanks! Tried it but got `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`. Will see what I can do to fix that.

Comment: @Winterflags, yep, this presumed you had all data like you first posted, I have a working example it is just ugly so I am trying to make it a bit nicer before posting

Comment: @Winterflags, try the edited answer, we can go with a regex if that does not work

Comment: Thanks a bunch! It finds BULL and BEAR correctly but writes only +100 or -100, no other multipliers. It's probably because my real DataFrame contains text after nX so I will have to fix that. `BULL AAPL X3 CBZ`

Comment: is there always one word after Xn/nX? if so try `spl = x.rsplit(None, 2)[-2].strip("Xx")`

Comment: In most cases, yes. Sorry about that, the original question kind of mushroomed a bit considering all the variables to take into account :) The multiplier is usually followed by a three letter word (no digits).

Comment: lol unfortunately so, it works now however! Thanks a thousand for your input!

Comment: No worries, just make sure we did not miss anything, you could use a regex with capture groups and check which one matched but it was uglier than splitting.

Comment: Everything seems to work perfectly satisfactory now, thanks! If you have the regex code ready you can post that too for reference, but otherwise I think we're happy with the current answer :)

Comment: No worries, I will wait until I get a nicer regex implementation together, splitting actually seems pretty efficient from running some tests so if it works then it is all good :)

Comment: If you still have the "ugly" regex solution for this I'm still interested. Split works great now, but I'm thinking of adding a few more situations where the names will follow a different convention.